# php multiple session from name files

Tags: php

i have code to save multiple name file in session,

php code

```
  <?php 
         session_start();

     $_SESSION['filest'] = array();

    if (isset($_FILES)) { 
    $total = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $file_uploaded = $_FILES['file']['name'];
       for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {

    $_SESSION['filest'][] = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
      }  } 

     var_dump($_SESSION['filest']);
     ?>
```

form code

```
<form id="htmlForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    Message: <input id="fileuploads" type="file" name="file[]" value="Hello HTML" multiple> 
    <input type="submit" value="Echo as HTML" /> 
</form>
```

my problem, can't get session arry.
when upload more file session not saved

Comment: Do you have `session_start()`?

Comment: yah i have it, but not show in question, i did't know to edit my question

Comment: under your tag (php) you should see edit link, don't you?

Comment: Do you know if the "if" statement is returning true?

Comment: Your php is formatted wrong. The second <?php tag is unnecessary and the closing }. Or, is this two separate scripts?

Comment: robert yes i know this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

I have tried your code and it's work for me.

**Form.php**

```
<form id="htmlForm" action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    Message: <input id="fileuploads" type="file" name="file[]" value="Hello HTML" multiple> 
    <input type="submit" value="Echo as HTML" /> 
</form>
```

**test.php**

```
$session_array = array();
if (isset($_FILES)) {
    $total = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $file_uploaded = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
        $session_array[] = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
    }
}
$_SESSION['filest'] = $session_array;
var_dump($_SESSION['filest']);
```

Comment: hi are your session saved after upload more file?

Comment: My frnd You miss `enctype="multipart/form-data"` .

Comment: still replace my array with new file, when i use my session in other files

Comment: Mean you use `session` another file to.

Comment: still my  code `$_SESSION['filest'] ` can't save my arry file name, when me upload other files

Comment: Now i changed code i tried this and it's work for me try this.

Comment: Make `$session_array` as global variable.

Comment: are you try `var_dump($_SESSION['filest']);` after upload 5 files? still not working sir, `$_SESSION['filest']` is empty

Comment: i tried test.php and Form.php in one files, its not working

Comment: Attempt to add a counter.

Answer (score 0):

To use the $_SESSION variable, you have to use `session_start()` at the top of every page.

Comment: I think this shouldn't be an answer but a comment

Comment: Why? The op said "my problem, can't get session arry." which means that he cannot get the session variable to be present. The problem comes when someone does not use `session_start()`.

Comment: well, i asked in comment and he said that he has `session_start()`

Comment: I will edit my answer when I find out what his problem actually is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `session_start();` function at beginning of all pages...

Comment: this should not be an answer!